# Java file I/O problem: file now written by newBufferedWriter

Tags: java, file, io

I wrote a small tool to print all the directory and file names under a given directory to a file. The program compiles fine, but after running the program, the file isn't written. This looks bizarre to me. The program code is listed below.

In line 49 in the code, when I used file only as the argument to the method, there was no problem and the output file was written. Please try out and see the result. But when I used file.getFileName() as the argument, the output file wasn't written at all!

Thank you very much for your help.

```
/**
 * This program walks a directory tree
 * and prints out the directory name and the file names under it.
 * @author Michael Mei
 * @version 1.0 22-03-2020
 */

package walkDirectory;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitResult.*;
import static java.nio.file.FileVisitOption.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;

public class DirWalkerPrinter extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private Path outPath;
    private Writer out;
    private int fileCount;
    private int dirCount;

    DirWalkerPrinter (Path outPath) throws IOException {
        this.outPath = outPath;
        out = Files.newBufferedWriter(outPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_16, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
    }

    public int getFileCount () {
        return fileCount;
    }

    public int getDirCount () {
        return dirCount;
    } 

    public void writeResults(Path p) throws IOException {
        // Using System.out.println(p.toString()) was also working.
        out.write(p.toString());
        out.write("\n");
    }

    public void done () throws IOException {
        out.write(fileCount + " of files found in " + dirCount);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile (Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        writeResults(file.getFileName()); // line 49
        fileCount++;
        return CONTINUE;
    }

    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory (Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        writeResults(dir);
        dirCount++;
        return CONTINUE;
    }
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed (Path file, IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return CONTINUE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("java DirWalkerPrinter source-path destination-file");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
        Path startingDir = Paths.get(args[0]);
        Path writeToDir = Paths.get(args[1]);
        DirWalkerPrinter dirWalkerPrinter = new DirWalkerPrinter(writeToDir);
        Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, dirWalkerPrinter);
        dirWalkerPrinter.done();
        int fileCount = dirWalkerPrinter.getFileCount();
        int dirCount = dirWalkerPrinter.getDirCount();
        System.out.println(fileCount + " of files found in " + dirCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks like the solution is to use `file` as the argument and not `file.getFIleName()`.  If 'file` was already working, what made you think that using `file.getFIleName()` would be an improvement?

Comment: Do you ever close the BufferedWriter?

Comment: @KevinAndersonThank you for your comment, Kevin. I used file.getFileName() because when written to a file, the names of files under the same directory would look almost identical save the file name proper at the end of the whole file name string. That would make the result unsightly. So, it was my intention to cut off the identical part of the file names under the same directory. That would make things look neat.

Comment: @NomadMakerThank you, NomadMaker. I forgot to close the BufferedWriter. Now I closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file.getFileName()
```

This function will only return the file name - without the full path. Your code will try to create the file in the same directory that you are executing from. (Because you input only the file name)

This is probably your issue.